# FInd Euler's totient exactly k times c++

Tags: c++

Given n & k. FInd Euler's totient exactly k times where n & k are very large number. I am trying with the below code. But its not so much optimized. Can anyone help with an efficient solution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b%a, a);
}


int phi(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;
    for (int i=2; i < n; i++)
        if (gcd(i, n) == 1)
            result++;
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    long n,i,k;
    cin >>n>>k;
    long a[n];
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      a[i] = phi(i);
    for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
      n = a[n];
    cout << n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
      n = a[n];` what is this loop doing?

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for code reviews. If you dont have any specific question or error, this is offtopic here

Comment: @SMA that loop is for iterating k times. ex. for n=12 and k=2 the answer will be 2 as φ(12)=4 and φ(4)=2

Comment: if you compute the gcd several times for the same parameters, memoization might help

Comment: You should just calculate phi till k and keep using the last value that you used. Also dont compute gcd every time, store i in a place where you could refer for gcd == 1.

Comment: @SMA  I shortened the code below. But still not figure out gcd memorization.  
  int main()
    {
        long n,i,k;
        cin >>n>>k;
        long a[n];
        for (i=1; i<=k; i++)
          n = phi(n);
     
        cout << n<<endl;
        return 0;
    }